# cURL Error (28): Operation timed out after

Tags: php, curl

Стоит задача парсинга robots.txt. Использую php curl.
На некоторых сайтах получаю ответ типа

```
cURL Error (28): Operation timed out after  30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Увеличение таймаута не решает проблему.
Сам код парсинга:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

$robots = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

для примера урл: https://www.adidas.ru/robots.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь в код свой строчку:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');

https://www.adidas.ru/robots.txt - отдается по дефолту gzip'ом, как видать и ряд других robots.txt с которыми у тебя проблемы.

**UPD**

Второй вариант это попросить не отдавать сервера контент gzip'ом передав заголовок

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['accept-encoding: deflate, br']);

это если вдруг у кого в сборках/версиях проблема с gzip

Comment: это частично решило проблему: если CURLOPT_USERAGENT передается браузер на windows, всё работает, но если браузер на макбуке, ошибка таже. Что может быть?

Comment: @Alex, а в чем проблема передавать всегда USERAGENT windows для данной задачи? Почему с макбуковским USERAGENT ошибка - вероятно нужно смотреть под ним хедеры и копать, но смысла именно для этой задачи не вижу.

Comment: действительно, на данный момент передавать windows  агента достаточно, но если смотреть в будущее, то скорее всего эта же технология, которая используется сейчас для макбуков, может быть использована и для всех, поэтому хотелось бы подстраховаться - понимать в чём причина

Comment: @Alex напиши url который под мак-юзером не парсится. И юзерагента конкретного полностью с которым ошибка.

Comment: конкретно для роботс сейчас не могу сказать, нет под рукой отчёта, но для примера url https://www.adidas.ru/static/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-CustomerFileStore/default/adidas-RU/ru_RU/sitemaps/adidas-RU-sitemap.xml, CURLOPT_USERAGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'

Comment: @Alex конкретно этот урл не парсится и под виндовским UA а решается curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7']); Старайся максимально подделать заголовки, смотри какие передает браузер. Особое внимание REFERER, USERAGENT, АCCEPT, cookie, различным POLICY. Имея не малый опыт работы с curl под php не помню чтобы я в итоге не мог спарсить им файл, дело в заголовках, обходе защит, порой в кривой логике cms которые парсишь. Вероятно это заслуживает отдельного вопроса с рядом примеров который не спарсил твой curl.

Comment: большое спасибо. наверное под виндовским он возможно игнорирует этот хидер, так как на санкбоксе прошел без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Один из вариантов возможных причин.</sub>

---

#### **[CURL - FAQ](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#curl_X_gives_me_HTTP_problems)** - 4.1 Проблемы при подключении к SSL серверам.

Иногда у `curl` возникают проблемы с подключением к `SSL` серверам при использовании `SSLeay` или `OpenSSL v0.9+`.

Многие старые SSL-сервера не работают с запросами `SSLv3`. Чтобы устранить эту проблему, добавьте в командной строке `curl` параметр `--sslv2`.

Были случаи, когда удаленному серверу не нравился запрос `SSLv2`, и вместо этого надо было использовать `SSLv3`. Параметр командной строки `--sslv3`.

Answer (score 0):

В ubuntu 16.04 существуют ограничения по подключению sslv3, видимо сервер запрещает другую версию 
https://ubuntugeeks.com/questions/33156/simple-way-of-enabling-sslv2-and-sslv3-in-openssl